# Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::post()

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, laravel-passport

Im trying to implement passport in lumen by using dusterio repo.
But when i do a migrate command (php artisan migrate), i got an error looks like :

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
```

Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::post()

somebody could help, what's wrong here?

Comment: can you run php artisan migrate -vvv and post the result?

Comment: Hi @pseudoanime , still the same result , 

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]     
  Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::post()